# CakePHP 3 good practice

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm doing some logic code in my entities and i don't know if it's a good practice. I got an object it belongs to a place. My PlacesTable works with treeBehavior and i want to know the place of an object but also the city where is the place:

I'm doing this and i want to know if it's a good practice:

```
class Object extends Entity
{
   protected $_accessible = [
       '*'    => true,
       'city' => true
   ];

   public function _getCity()
   {
      $Places = TableRegistry::get('Zones');
      $cityId = $Places->getRoot($this->place);
      return $Places->get($cityId);
   }
}
```

Then my virtual field city is now a CityEntity

Comment: I don't personally think that accessing the table from the entity is a good idea

Comment: So is it possible to build an association with condition based on TreeBehavior finder `path` ? CakePHP 3.x allow us to deal with new concept with high interoperability so sometimes i'm a bit confused of what i can do or not. Anyway you did great with this release awesome work.

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible. Have you tried it?

Comment: no i didn't try yet but with i'll work on it and give you some feedback